# Custom IDs for input and label using Simple Form's radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

I am creating multiple forms for the same resource in one page. Each of these forms has radio buttons.

However, Simple Form assigns the same ID to the same radio button options across all forms, causing a conflict.

How can I namespace each form, or select custom IDs for both each label and input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use multiple `simple_form_for` methods in your view, they are just [clever wrappers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/e81af052f4bbe9e17e38c668116cd1846c6d275c/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb#L13) around the `form_for` built-in rails helper which supports the `namespace` option. Quoting from the [`form_for` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

> `:namespace` - A namespace for your form to ensure uniqueness of id attributes on form elements. The namespace attribute will be prefixed with underscore on the generated HTML id.

So, something like the following should work:

```
<%= simple_form_for @resource, namespace: "first_form" do |f| %>
...
<% end %>


<%= simple_form_for @resource, namespace: "second_form" do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: So simple! works perfectly. For my namespace i used `resource_#{resource.id}`, and replace resource by my model name of course.